# Error on updating or upgrading ubuntu because of dependencies

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, updates, dependencies

When I install or update anything i get errors like these below.

Could I force a complete uninstallation of these packages or other similar option to avoid these errors?

For this I used synaptic but I also tried with apt install or remove

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove ...
```

**ERRORS apt:**

```
...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-pysqlite2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 470240 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-mysql.connector (2.0.4-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-mysql.connector.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-mysql.connector.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-mysql.connector (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-mysql.connector.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-mysql.connector.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-mysql.connector
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
...
```

**ERRORS synaptic:**

```
E: python-ecdsa: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
E: python-mysql.connector: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
E: python-ptyprocess: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reinstall broken packages, as is it could be caused by incorrect installation of a software.

```
for package in $(sudo apt-get upgrade 2>&1 | grep "warning: files list file for package '" | grep -Po "[^'\n ]+'" | grep -Po "[^']+"); do sudo apt-get install --reinstall "$package"; done
```

This script reinstalls every package that outputs `warning: files list file for package` in the process of `apt-get upgrade`.

It will take longer time as it cycles every package.

If the script does not work, then you should do something like this with every package (currently, `python-pysqlite2`) that shows the aforementioned warning:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pysqlite2
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing)